# AWS - How can I create event source mapping for fifo lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create an event source mapping with the AWS cli, but I keep getting a combination of errors that don't add up. Here's what I've tried:

1. `aws lambda create-event-source-mapping --function-name someFunctionName --batch-size 100 --starting-position LATEST --event-source arn:aws:sqs:eu-central-1:someARN:SomeQueue.fifo`
   This results in: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateEventSourceMapping operation: StartingPosition
   is not valid for SQS event sources.
2. Then I try without the starting position: `aws lambda create-event-source-mapping --function-name someFunctionName --batch-size 100 --event-source arn:aws:sqs:eu-central-1:someARN:SomeQueue.fifo` which results in:  error: argument --starting-position is required

Am I missing something? How am I supposed to call this command?

`aws -version` tells me I'm running `aws-cli/1.15.10 Python/2.7.9 Windows/2012Server botocore/1.10.10`. Is this just an out of date version?

So, as I'm writing this question I upgrade the cli to 2.0.9 and option 2 works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded the cli to 2.0.9 and option 2 works!!!